# Jqplot chart with 2 series not displayed correctly

Tags: javascript, jqplot, linechart

I have a `jqplot graph` that I'm using to display 2 series next to each other. The `X-axis` is based on a date element and the `Y-axis` on a percentage value that ranges between -10% en 10%, but that's not really relevant.

Both series have the same number of elements and the x-axis value is identical for each entry of the two series, but the result I'm getting is this.

[image]

It seems that some elements in the collection of elements that I'm passing on to the `jqplot` library have some corrupt data (on the x-axis, so the date value in my case), but I've checked the collection of elements and it is sorted on the date, Not sure why it's not being rendered correctly though.

Has anyone else here had a similar problem?

Thanks

Comment: and printing elements for x-axis returns normal dates? maybe date parsing is bad in some cases.

Comment: Dates are converted to an integer value, and still ok, sorted correctly I mean.

Comment: isnt it more usually to use YYYY-MM-DD as a data source for charts? why using integers?

Comment: btw there is [dateAxisRendered](http://www.jqplot.com/tests/date-axes.php) so that you dont have to use values in ms.

Comment: Using $.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer instead of CategoryAxisRenderer has fixed the problem. Thanks for the tip :)